# Can Xamarin.Forms be used to make a windows desktop application? (No UWP/Store)

Tags: c#, windows, xamarin, uwp

My client asked for an application to run on Ios/Android/WindowsPhone a year ago. We proposed to use Xamarin.Forms and for the Ios/Android part all went perfect. We are now facing the problem of Windows Phone. The platform is basically dead so the client asked if it's possibile to convert the app from mobile to desktop without using the windows store.

This application will be used on multiple pcs ranging from windows 7 to 8.1 to 10.
I know that it's possibile to reuse the C# code from Xamarin on .Net, but I was wondering if it's possible a direct export of the project from Xamarin.

Thanks.

Comment: You can try using this [https://github.com/jvlppm/xamarin-forms-wpf](https://github.com/jvlppm/xamarin-forms-wpf). But I'm not 100% sure it will help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I was looking for an official answer/tutorial. Implementing my project using a discontinued (?) plugin is not possible.

Comment: I don't think there's an official tutorial or even an official "way" of doing that.

Comment: The only Windows platform officially supported by Forms is UWP.

Comment: Hi, @Jason . Do you have a link that state that? Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/#Universal_Windows_Platform

Comment: All that you need is change UI (rewrite all xaml of Xamarin to xaml of wpf)
or
you can update all your references to Xamarin 3.0... and add Xamarin wpf package from nuget.